# Is there any documented game by Benjamin Blumenfeld where he played Blumenfeld Gambit?

Tags: history, gambits

Is there any documented game by [Benjamin Blumenfeld](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessplayer?pid=20462) where he played [Blumenfeld Gambit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blumenfeld_Gambit)?

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry I have no sources, but I have read somewhere (maybe in Yermolinsky's *The Road to Chess Improvement* - but apparently not) that no, there isn't any known game of Blumenfeld employing his eponym opening. The gambit is named such just because Alekhine, when annotating his famous Blumenfeld [win](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1012085) against Tarrasch, wrote that "4...b5 is an idea by Blumenfeld".